# unexpected value exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I got Following Error in Laravel. **UnexpectedValueException** **The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(),"boolean" given.**

My Helper Code is :

```
function checkunitconversionexist($itemid,$itemunits){

    for($i=0; $i<count($itemid); $i++){     

    $finditemsinfos=DB::table('items')->Where('id',$itemid[$i])->first();   


    if($finditemsinfos->unit == $itemunits[$i]){        

    return 1;

    } else { 

    $chkunitconversionexist=DB::table('unitconversion')->Where('itemsid',$itemid[$i])->Where('unit_name',$finditemsinfos->unit)->Where('subunit_name',$itemunits[$i])->get();

    if(count($chkunitconversionexist) > 0){ 

    return 1;

    } else {    

    return 0;   

    }


    }

    }   
}
```

Comment: That's pretty clear. You return a boolean. But it seems that a string is expected.

Comment: How you call `checkunitconversionexist` method, provide that line code

Comment: checkunitconversionexist($data['product'],$data['unit']); @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: And at which line you facing this exception?